# What can go wrong when I define a macro and just use a rare enough name for a temporary variable?

Tags: macros, lisp, scope

[Let Over Lambda Chapter 3 Section 'Unwanted Capture'](http://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/guest/chap3.html#sec_5) says:

"Surely we can think of rare enough names so that the problem never shows up. Yes, in many cases, packages and smart variable naming can solve the problem of variable capture. However, most serious variable capture bugs don't arise in code directly created by a programmer. Most variable capture problems only surface **when other macros use your macro (combine with your macro) in ways you didn't anticipate.**"

and then it doesn't give me an example for the bold part. What would be one of such examples? Imagine a hypothetical Lisp dev team where its mad boss banned the use of gensym or anything that creates uninterned symbols and the programmers simply resort to throwing alphanumeric dice to come up with random variable names like temp-27s63f8sk2n or sum-3t84hj4df whenever they miss gensym. What would be an example where the team will get in trouble?

Speaking of which, Emacs 24.3.1 defines dotimes and dolist without using uninterned symbols. Weird.

Comment: Why are people voting to close this? It's a genuine and complex question.

Answer (score 2):

OK, then I'd propose automating that process of "throwing alphanumeric dice".  Of course, it doesn't have to be random, you could just use a counter.  Additionally, it would be nice to be able to specify a prefix, for debugging.  Oh wait, that is exactly what `gensym` does.

Comment: Gensym returns uninterned symbols. The hypothetical team only uses INTERNED symbols. If the team relies on `intern-gensym` which is like `gensym` except it returns interned symbols, then they are going to get in trouble because the names G10, G11, G12.... are not rare enough, and there is a chance that users of macros would use such variable names, and such an example is given in the linked Let Over Lambda article.

Comment: If the team uses interned symbols with random postfix, issues of such an example can be avoid. Then the article says there is yet another way to get in trouble, the bold part in the quote. Can the bold part get the team in trouble?

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises when you re-use your own macro in some other context and your cleverly namespaced variables are effectively then redundant, since they are all on the same namespace.

I can think of an example being when using a closure that accesses a variable in an enclosing `(let)`, but is passed to a macro that also uses an enclosing `(let)` defining a "safe" variable with a name clash. It's a contrived example, sorry, I can't think of a real-world case right now.

```
(defmacro my/a (x)
  (let ((my/safe-name x))
    `(progn ,(my/b (lambda () my/safe-name))
            ,my/safe-name)))

(defmacro my/b (f)
  `(let ((my/safe-name 4))
     (when (evenp (funcall ,f))
       (print "F is even!"))))

(my/a 3) ; will print "F is even", but it shouldn't
```

Comment: A usual dev team will write that with *two* gensym calls or make-symbol calls. The hypothetical dev team in question will run their pseudorandom alphanumeric postfix generator *twice*. So it will be ((my/safe-name-6kuyd4kq x)) in my/a and ((my/safe-name-pqedzkwg 4)) in my/b. For this team to get in trouble, we would need code that expands to code that somehow pick up my/safe-name-6kuyd4kq and make it clash with itself in some way. I suspect this is what the bold part is about, except it lacks an example, so I cannot be sure.

Comment: Using gensym is exactly what Doug Hoyte suggests as the solution to unwanted capture. You only have problems if you neglect to use gensyms. That's what Hoyte is trying to say. At this point in the book, he's assuming you don't yet know about gensyms, only hand-picked (but namespaced) variable names.